# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation,

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, owin

I am having this error ONLY after I added the assembly line on the startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(InnovationInABoxWebApi.App_Start.Startup))]
namespace InnovationInABoxWebApi.App_Start
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

this is package.json

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.0.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.5" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.5" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.5" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.2.5" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="5.2.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.2.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net45" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="5.2.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Full error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.



WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].



Stack Trace: 



[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory.WsFedMetadataRetriever.GetSigningKeys(String metadataEndpoint, TimeSpan backchannelTimeout, HttpMessageHandler backchannelHttpHandler) +0
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory.WsFedCachingSecurityKeyProvider.RetrieveMetadata() +146
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory.WsFedCachingSecurityKeyProvider..ctor(String metadataEndpoint, ICertificateValidator backchannelCertificateValidator, TimeSpan backchannelTimeout, HttpMessageHandler backchannelHttpHandler) +296
   Owin.WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationExtensions.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(IAppBuilder app, WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions options) +163
   InnovationInABoxWebApi.App_Start.Startup.ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) in C:\Users\valencil\source\repos\InnovationInABoxWebApi2\InnovationInABoxWebApi\App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs:15
   InnovationInABoxWebApi.App_Start.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in C:\Users\valencil\source\repos\InnovationInABoxWebApi2\InnovationInABoxWebApi\Startup.cs:15
```

Comment: try installing this package via Nuget Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation -Version 5.2.0.0

Comment: thanks that worked

Comment: add it as an answer to accept it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try installing this package via

```
Nuget Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation -Version 5.2.0.0
```

Comment: I'm having the same problems as @Luis Valencia had. I've installed the NuGet package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation as you recommended. But it hasn't fixed my problem. The weird thing is that this project had been working fine just this morning. Now it isn't.

Comment: @Rod: Same here..  Please confirm in Package Manager Console that you've set your default project then repeat the Install-Package command.

Comment: @BillVo, odd thing happened for me. Even though I had a problem after installing Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation back on June 5, the next day I could work with it fine. I don't understand why that made a difference, but since I couldn't duplicate the problem, I just went with it as it was.

Comment: this is now: Nuget install Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation -Version 5.2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify Web.Config for dependentAssembly "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation" old and new version number. Visual Studio default template appended one extra "0" to the version number on the end. 
   Ex. Actual value: oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.1.0.0" newVersion="5.2.1.0.0"
   Replace value to: oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.1.0" newVersion="5.2.1.0"
2. Open Package Manager Console and run
   Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WsFederation -Version 5.2.1.0

This step resolved my issue